# `\Block` does not accept `\lstinline`

Tags: listings, verbatim, nicematrix

I would like to typeset verbatim style commands from `\lstinline` in `\Block` command, but it does not seem to work

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinestyle{verbatim}{basicstyle=\ttfamily,language={[LaTeX]TeX}}

\begin{document} 
    
\lstinline[style=verbatim]|\mathcal|
    
\begin{NiceTabularX}{\textwidth}[]{*{11}X[c, t]}
    
    \Block{1-}{\lstinline[style=verbatim]|\mathcal|} & & & & & & & & & &
    \\
    
\end{NiceTabularX}
    
\end{document}
```

**Edit**
From the answers of [muzimuzhi Z](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/622839/136098) and [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/622851/136098), it seems two solutions are possible as follows

### Solution 1

Providing `\newsavebox{\lstinlineBox}` then putting the argument inside an `lrbox` environment as follows

```
\begin{lrbox}{\lstinlineBox}\lstinline[style=verbatim]|\mathcal|\end{lrbox}
```

Then we may post the box as follows

```
\usebox{\lstinlineBox}
```

**Advantages of this method**

1. It applies to `\lstinline` from `listings` which helps process codes according to pre-defined styles for many programming language
2. You type anything in the argument of `\lstinline` and it would appear exactly as typeset (i.e., no escaping rules needed). The argument gets highlighted according to your editor preferences

**Disadvantages of this method**

1. Font size is modified and is not inherited from the surrounding text

### Solution 2

Using `\EscVerb{\\mathcal}` from `fvextra` package

**Advantages of this method**

1. Easier than `listings`
2. Font size is inherited from the surrounding text

**Disadvantages of this method**

1. You need to fulfil escaping rules which are available in the documentation of `fvextra` package (page 14 for v1.4). For example, to typeset '', you must enter `\\`
2. No highlighting of the argument of `\EscVerb`, which means it is harder to modify and read

I think it is good when to provide a solution which overcomes such limitation in a neat fashion.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{verbatim}{basicstyle=\ttfamily,language={[LaTeX]TeX}}

\newsavebox{\lstinlineBox}

\usepackage{fvextra}

\begin{document} 
    
    \begin{lrbox}{\lstinlineBox}\lstinline[style=verbatim]|\mathcal|\end{lrbox}
    \section{\usebox{\lstinlineBox}}
    
    \noindent
    \begin{NiceTabularX}{\textwidth}[]{*{11}X[c, t]}
        \begin{lrbox}{\lstinlineBox}\lstinline[style=verbatim]|\mathcal|\end{lrbox}
        \Block{1-}{\usebox{\lstinlineBox}} \\
        0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & \lstinline[style=verbatim]|\mathcal|
    \end{NiceTabularX}
    
    \bigskip
    \begin{lrbox}{\lstinlineBox}\lstinline[style=verbatim]|\mathcal|\end{lrbox}
    \section{\EscVerb{\\mathcal}}
    
    \noindent
    \begin{NiceTabularX}{\textwidth}[]{*{11}X[c, t]}
        \Block{1-}{\EscVerb{\\mathcal}} \\
        0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & \EscVerb{\\mathcal}
    \end{NiceTabularX}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/622359/how-to-get-section-command-to-accept-verbatim-text-with-inside-it#comment1553631_622359

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, is this a limitation which may never be solved?

Comment: there is always something you can do but basically it is built in to the language,  `\mathcal` has already been read by `\Block` and so tokenised (actually NiceTabular grabs the environment body so `\mathcal` was tokenised even earlier), so it is too late to change the tokenisation rules and read it as `\ m a t h c a l` rather than a single token, this applies to verb, lstinline, minted, and applies to all surrounding commands,

Comment: you could typeset the lstinline first in a `lrbox` environment then use `\usebox{\yourbox}` to use it at that point.

Comment: If you are open to other verbatim packages, then with `fvextra` you can use `\Block{1-}{\EscVerb{\\mathcal}}` and with `minted` (which is built on top of `fvextra` and uses python library `pygments` to highlight the code) welcome to try my experimental hence not fully-tested `\EscMintinline` provided in [this issue comment](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/288#issuecomment-756418475). In your example, try `\Block{1-}{\EscMintinline{tex}{\\mathcal}}`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. For information, `{NiceTabular}` does not grab the whole body of the environment (excepted when the key `light-syntax` is in force). However, of course, that doesn't change that `\Block` will tokenize its argument... That was only for information.

Comment: @F.Pantigny ah thanks, I did wonder if I ought to check first:-)

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ. Your answer is interesting. It seems that `\EscVerb{\\mathcal}` works well. Can you post an answer?

Answer (score 2):

If you are open to other verbatim packages and prefer in-place input (compared to [David Carlisle's suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/622675/block-does-not-accept-lstinline?noredirect=1#comment1554565_622675)), then you can use

- `\EscVerb` from [`fvextra`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fvextra) package or
- my experimental hence not fully-tested `\EscMintinline` depending on [`minted`](https://ctan.org/pkg/minted), whose definition is originally posted as an [issue comment](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/288#issuecomment-756418475).

`fvextra` has only verbatim + line breaking, `minted` is based on `fvextra` and provides code highlighting through python library `pygments` (`-shell-escape` required).

Package [`cprotect`](https://ctan.org/pkg/cprotect) may be another option but I didn't make it.

An example showing both `\EscVerb` and `\EscMintinline`:

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

% \usepackage{listings}
% \lstdefinestyle{verbatim}{basicstyle=\ttfamily,language={[LaTeX]TeX}}
\usepackage{minted}

\makeatletter
%
% Similar to \EscVerb.
%
% \EscMintinline[options]{<language>}{<backslash-escaped text>}
%
% copied from https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/288#issuecomment-756418475
\def\EscMintinline{%
  \FVExtraRobustCommand
  \RobustEscMintinline
  \FVExtraUnexpandedReadOArgMArgEscVArg}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \FVExtraUnexpandedReadOArgMArgEscVArg { o m m } {%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {\FVExtraAlwaysUnexpanded
      {\FVExtraUnexpandedReadOArgMArgEscVArg{#2}{#3}}}
    {\FVExtraAlwaysUnexpanded
      {\FVExtraUnexpandedReadOArgMArgEscVArg[#1]{#2}{#3}}}%
}

\newrobustcmd\RobustEscMintinline[2][]{%
  % similar to \mintinline
  \begingroup
  \setboolean{minted@isinline}{true}%
  \minted@configlang{#2}%
  \setkeys{minted@opt@cmd}{#1}%
  \minted@fvset
  \begingroup
  \@ifnextchar\bgroup
    {\FVExtraDetokenizeREscVArg{\minted@inline@iii}}%
    {\PackageError{minted}%
     {\string\EscMintinline\space delimiters must be paired curly braces in this context}%
     {Delimit argument with curly braces}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document} 

% \lstinline[style=verbatim]|\mathcal| abc

\begin{NiceTabularX}{\textwidth}[hvlines]{*{11}X[c, t]}
    
    \Block{1-}{\EscVerb{\$\\mathcal{L}\\{f\\}(s) = \$}}
      & & & & & & & & & & \\
    \Block{1-}{\EscMintinline{tex}{\$\\mathcal{L}\\{f\\}(s) = \$}}
      & & & & & & & & & & \\

\end{NiceTabularX}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Update for `minted` v2.7 (2022-12-12)

`minted` v2.7 reimplemented `\mintinline`, making the old `\EscMintinline` incompatible.  Since a (non-user command) `\RobustMintInline` is introduced with v2.7, I decided to make the revised command using uppercased i as well. So it's now called `\EscMintInlint`.

Example with updated experimental implementation of `\EscMintInline`

```tex
% !TeX document-id = {4f64184d-77b8-4fbf-a0e2-f523f935f052}
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///pdflatex/{%.tex} -shell-escape "%.tex"
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

% \usepackage{listings}
% \lstdefinestyle{verbatim}{basicstyle=\ttfamily,language={[LaTeX]TeX}}
\usepackage{minted}

\makeatletter
%
% Similar to \EscVerb.
%
% \EscMintinline[options]{<language>}{<backslash-escaped text>}
%
% copied from https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/288#issuecomment-1501540637
\def\EscMintInline{%
  \FVExtraRobustCommand
  \RobustEscMintInline
  \FVExtraUnexpandedReadOArgMArgEscVArg}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \FVExtraUnexpandedReadOArgMArgEscVArg { o m m } {%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {\FVExtraAlwaysUnexpanded
      {\FVExtraUnexpandedReadOArgMArgEscVArg{#2}{#3}}}
    {\FVExtraAlwaysUnexpanded
      {\FVExtraUnexpandedReadOArgMArgEscVArg[#1]{#2}{#3}}}%
}

% similar to \RobustMintInline
\newrobustcmd{\RobustEscMintInline}[2][]{%
  \ifbool{FVExtraRobustCommandExpanded}%
   {\@ifnextchar\bgroup
     {\FVExtraDetokenizeREscVArg{\RobustMintInlineProcess{#1}{#2}}}%
     {\PackageError{minted}%
       {Inline delimiters must be paired curly braces in this context}%
       {Use curly braces as delimiters}}}%
   {\FVExtraDetokenizeREscVArg{\RobustMintInlineProcess{#1}{#2}}}}
\makeatother


\begin{document} 

% \lstinline[style=verbatim]|\mathcal| abc

\begin{NiceTabularX}{\textwidth}[hvlines]{*{11}X[c, t]}

    \Block{1-}{\EscVerb{\$\\mathcal{L}\\{f\\}(s) = \$}}
      & & & & & & & & & & \\
    \Block{1-}{\EscMintInline{tex}{\$\\mathcal{L}\\{f\\}(s) = \$}}
      & & & & & & & & & & \\

\end{NiceTabularX}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might define a `Blockenv` environment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{verbatim}{basicstyle=\ttfamily,language={[LaTeX]TeX}}

\newsavebox{\Blockenvbox}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{Blockenv}{O{}m}
 {\begin{lrbox}{\Blockenvbox}}
 {\end{lrbox}\Block[#1]{#2}{\usebox\Blockenvbox}}

\begin{document} 
    
\noindent
\begin{NiceTabularX}{\textwidth}[]{*{11}X[c, t]}
\begin{Blockenv}{1-}
  \lstinline[style=verbatim]|\mathcal|
\end{Blockenv} \\
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10
\end{NiceTabularX}
    
\bigskip

\noindent
\begin{NiceTabularX}{\textwidth}[]{*{11}X[c, t]}
\begin{Blockenv}[l]{1-}
  \lstinline[style=verbatim]|\mathcal|
\end{Blockenv} \\
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10
\end{NiceTabularX}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

***Caveat.*** When `\lstinline` is issued inside `Blockenv`, there is a spurious `Overfull \hbox` message that probably comes from the measuring phase, but doesn't seem to affect the final result.